# How to find IV from market prices accodring to Bergomi

Tags: option-pricing, black-scholes-pde

I was conviced to read Bergomis book on stochasic volatility to learn how options are traded in practice. He basically writes that the probabilisitc side is rather useless and that one only uses the PDE as an accouting tool, which makes sense to me given the difficulty to model stocks. Anyway, I am just on the 1st chapter, he might have something to say about modelling later.

To the question!

My interpretation of his introduction is that IV, i.e $\hat{\sigma}$, is a number related to breakeven in the PnL which in turn is related to a family of parameterised(in IV) black-scholes equatations, which the price of the option must statisfy(as usual).

He then elaobeates on how to find this IV when there is a deep and liquid market for the option and that, from what I can tell, is done by finding the right BS PDE(within the family) that matches up to market price.

Am I thinking about this the right way?

Here is the book

https://www.lorenzobergomi.com/_files/ugd/c4ff5c_ba17141422d44ba99daf19ee2b931544.pdf

The relevant parts are on pages 2-5. In particular that $(1.4)$ is a family of PDEs in $\sigma$ and that finding the IV correspond the finding which of these that match up with market price as mentioned on page $5$ in the 3rd paragraph

Answer (score 2):

In short, the implied volatility is the value of $\sigma$ that you input in the Black-Scholes-Merton equation such that the BSM price = Market price.

To find it, you need to use some Numerical procedure (there is no close form solution).

- First, extract all the parameter available (corresponding to your market price quote), e.g. stock price, stock, time to maturity, risk free rate, dividend yield, etc...
- Then you input and fix these parameter into the BSM equation so you express the equation as a function of $\sigma$ only i.e BSM($\sigma$)
- Finally you implement a numerical procedure(e.g. Newton's method, Secant method etc...) to find the root of the equation:
  Market Price$ - BSM(\sigma) = 0$

ps: My answer is based on the title of the question only. There was no question in the body.

---

useful links:

https://www.wallstreetmojo.com/implied-volatility-formula/

https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/032515/what-options-implied-volatility-and-how-it-calculated.asp

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithms

Comment: @LvM_ Ive added the explicit question now, sorry for forgetting that before

Comment: @nbbo2 I think this corresponds to my interpretation, finding the root, is finding the right parameter $\sigma$  and BSM($\sigma$) is a family of PDEs index in $\sigma$.

Hence this implicity answers my question with a yes, i.e we are indeed finding IV by finding the right PDE withinthe family. Maybe this should be added to the answer, which in it of itself is also great info on computing it